# Installing Packages

Tags: miktex

I am trying to install a new package to use in my document, but it tells me the following: The remote package repository is outdated. You have to choose another repository." Any idea on what might be the cause of that and how to fix it?

Comment: Open the MikTeX package manager (rather than auto-install when you compile a document). You will find a method for changing the location where you get packages.

Comment: Tried to do so, but the problem is where do I find a reliable directory for packages online.

Comment: Ah. That might depend on where you live. In the USA, there are several universities that maintain a TeX mirror. Also hoobly.com is reliable. In your own location, look through the list of available mirrors, and try the nearest university.

Comment: Here is a list of current repositories: https://miktex.org/pkg/repositories